# What is the domain of convergence of this power series: $\sum_{n>1}{\frac{n^2}{n!}x^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the domain of convergence of this power series: $$\sum_{n>1}{\frac{n^2}{n!}x^n}$$
I tryed to calculate the radius, but I think that I did the limit wrong.

Comment: Ratio test gives $R=+\infty$

Comment: You first need to calculate the Interval of Convergence. Only after that you may consider the Radius of Convergence. Now can you apply the Ratio Test for this exercise?

Comment: @imranfat What is the interval of convergence

Comment: It is an interval of $x$ for which the series converges. Kind of like domain. In your example, the interval is from -infinity to infinity (meaning all real numbers), and hence, the radius of convergence is infinity, as Abdallah indicated

Comment: But in order to know the intervel of convergence you dont have to know the Radius? I mean x is not dependent of radius?

Comment: @NeacsuMihai, No, that is not needed. You can first calculate the Interval of Convergence and from there obtain the Radius of Convergence. But Falcon's approach is also fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  [d'Alembert rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the radius of the given power series is the inverse of the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2(n+1)}=0.$$

Comment: Ok, so i got the same limit (zero), so that means that ${R=+\infty}$ So what does this say about my range of convergence?

Comment: The given power series is hence defined on $\mathbb{C}$ if you work with complex variables or on $\mathbb{R}$ if you keep real variables. Both ways there is no obstruction to its convergence.

Comment: The book where I got this exercise says that I have to get the domain of convergence between ${(\frac{-1}{e},\frac{1}{e})}$, I assume it was misspelled.

Comment: That must indeed be a mistake of the book...

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{  \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}}{  \frac{n^2}{n!}  }=0$$

$\implies R=+\infty$

and

$\forall x\in \mathbb R$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}x^n=$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}x^n=$$

$$(x^2+x)e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Recalling from [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), the $n! =\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{ n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$, then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n^2x^n}{n!}\right|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n^{2/n}|x|}{(2\pi n)^{1/2n}(n/e)}\right)=0$$

Therefore, from the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test), the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark